# Power Pivot Calculated field (Teradata)

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I imported data from teradata through a query in powerpivot data model. But I am unable to add a calculated field with absolutely any formula using table columns.

I tried

```
Calculated Field 1:=Query[AccountsWithOffers]
```

But even this didn't result in anything.I am receiving a Semantic Error 'accounts with offer cant be determined.

My table columns are

```
touch_date
area
region
channel
OfferMade
AccountswithOffers
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Fields (or "Measures") cannot reference "naked" columns. There must be an aggregation of data to return a single, well-defined result from the filter context. COUNT(Query[AccountsWithOffers]) should return a result if Query[AccountsWithOffers] is a numeric field. If it is not COUNTA(Query[AccountsWithOffers]) will work.